# Edit, select value from UITableView on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a list of names, representing server configurations. I want the user to be able to select a server configuration, add a server config, edit a server config, or just cancel out of the view and return to the main view. I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to achieve all of that functionality in this view.

To select, the user should be able to just tap the server config name and a check will appear next to the name then the user is taken back to the main view automatically (or use a save button instead?). To edit the server config, I would also like the user to be able to tap the server config name and be taken to a detail screen where changes can be made. How can I accomplish both since I want both to be done by tapping the server name (row)? Right now the cancel button seems out of place since the screen is accessed via a UINavigationController.

Any suggestions?

[alt text http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/6448/screenshot20100325at541.png](http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/6448/screenshot20100325at541.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a **detail disclosure button**? this effectively gives you two "hot points" on each tableViewCell:
1- The detail disclosure button itself which, according to Apple's HIG, should take you to a detail view.
2- The rest of the cell which you could use to make your selection and pop the view controller.

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```